# How can I do "export $(dbus-launch) in booting

Tags: yocto, dbus, gdbus

I'm using GDbus and make a dbus communication.
It using sesstion bus.

Problem is dbus-launch.

I was running dbus in Yocto with c++11.
And, I have to export $(dbus-launch).

But, I want to export $(dbus-launch) or same thing in booting time.
Because dbus start by systemd.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to have a recipe that adds environment variable:

```
SRC_URI +=  "file://dbus-env.sh"

do_install_append() {
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}${sysconfdir}/profile.d
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/dbus-env.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/profile.d/
}

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/profile.d/dbus-env.sh"
```

With dbus-env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

export $(dbus-launch)
```

Comment: I was trying to install script in /etc/profile.d and reboot. But looks like export was not working.

Comment: is your script has execution rights ? `chmod ugo+x /etc/profile.d/yourscript.sh`

Which other app needs the exported variables?

Comment: I missed checking mode. I'll try again.

Comment: This is can make environment. But profile.d is working after login. I need working before login.

Comment: if you use systemd as init, you can add `EnvironmentFile=/tmp/dbus-session` and `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/dbus-session-env.sh` with `dbus-session-env.sh` doing `dbus-launch > /tmp/dbus-session` Then you can pass `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID` in `ExecStart`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc` :

```
eval \`dbus-launch --auto-syntax`
```

this will export `"DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"` and `"DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID"` with proper values

you can also use [this script](https://gist.github.com/XayOn/3911619):

```
[[ -n $SSH_CLIENT ]] && export $(cat /proc/$(command pgrep -u "$USER"  -f -- "dbus-daemon --session" )/environ| tr '\0' '\n' | command grep "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=")
```